# how to create an if statement on google sheets based on two rows of data

Tags: javascript, if-statement

[image: Click to view data]
I need to create an IF statement for the following:

If the column 'Device Type' contains the value ' PIR' delete row, 
If the row above 'PIR' has alarm type ' reset' and has the same time as the PIR row, delete this row too,

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
 =IF(G2="PIR";IF(F1="Reset";TRUE;FALSE);FALSE)
```

In script it would be something like

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rowsToDelete = [];
  for (i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    try {
      if (values[i][0] === "Reset" && values[i+1][1] === "PIR") {
        rowsToDelete.push(i);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      continue;
    }
  }
  for (i=rowsToDelete.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
  }
};
```

Modify it to fit your sheet

Comment: Through script, how do you use that to then delete both rows

Comment: Thanks so much, Its basically what i had, but nothing seems to be happening when i run it,

Comment: Maybe use Logger.log() to make sure you get the correct values from your sheet when you run it